# Does Spring Security's RunAsManagerImpl work?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is this a bug in Spring Security's `RunAsManagerImpl`, or are my expectations wrong?

My understanding of the (limited) documentation, is that with a `RunAsManagerImpl` defined in my config if I call `doFoo()` in the following:

```
@Secured({"ROLE_FOO", "RUN_AS_BAR"})
public void doFoo() {
  doBar();
}

@Secured("ROLE_BAR")
public void doBar() {
  // ...
}
```

then, provided the current `Authentication` has the role "FOO", `doBar()` will execute successfully.

But it doesn't, Spring throws an AccessDeniedException. However, changing `doBar()`'s annotation to:

```
@Secured("ROLE_RUN_AS_BAR")
```

works successfully.

Upon examination of the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/RunAsManagerImpl.java), the reason is fairly clear - if it encounters an attribute that starts with "RUN_AS_", it creates:

```
GrantedAuthority extraAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(getRolePrefix() + attribute.getAttribute());
```

where, by default:

```
private String rolePrefix = "ROLE_";
```

So the authority that is applied is "ROLE_RUN_AS_BAR", which doesn't seem right at all. Is this a bug that I should raise, or have I misunderstood the intended use of this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the expected behavior, as described in the documentation:

> The created GrantedAuthorityImpls will be prefixed with a special
>   prefix indicating that it is a role (default prefix value is ROLE_),
>   and then the remainder of the RUN_AS_ keyword. For example, RUN_AS_FOO
>   will result in the creation of a granted authority of ROLE_RUN_AS_FOO.

The purpose of such basic implementation is not to impersonate a user, but to acquire a "technical role". For example, some part of your code should require a technical role of "database manager". No user has this role but I can be acquired programmatically.

Of course, you can bypass this code by just updating the `Authentication` in `SecurityContextHolder`, but having a central implementation point to "upgrade" an `Authentication` object can be more secure when used by a jvm securitymanager.

However, the `RunAsManager` is a really simple interface, in order to be easily reimplemented: If the default behavior doesn't match what you need, you only have one method to reimplement.

Comment: You're right, of course, thank you. For some reason I'd read "the remainder of the RUN_AS_ keyword" to mean without the "RUN_AS_" prefix, and somehow managed to ignore the clear example they give. As you say, it's easy to enough to reimplement, I was just confused by my misunderstanding of the docs.